# Posting form with Ajax to a different server getting is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

```
  $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

This line seems to work for accessing pages from another server via ajax but when I try to post data to another server I'm still getting an error even though the line above is in my script.

Here is the Ajax I'm using to post the data.

```
         $.ajax({
            url: "' . base_url('pagehere') . '",
            type: "POST",
            data: "type=pform&ip="+ip+"&host_server="+host_server+"&mediabar="+mediabar+fields,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#panelform").hide();
                $(".pthankyou").show();
            }
            });
```

Here is what I have on the page I'm posting to:

```
        $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
```

I'm not sure what else I need to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set your ajax with credentials:

```
$.ajax({...
xhrFields:{
        withCredentials: true
      },
});
```

Comment: And then do I need $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true") this on the page I'm sending  it to?

Comment: @flyersun i never needed that for allow origin requests, try without, i mean if request is ajax, once ajax request got permission, you can/should do anything normally

Comment: When you say to be sure the server is ok accepting your request, what do I need to check?